# What does "Своя ноша не тяжела" mean?

Tags: пословицы

Вчера я отдал свою швейную машинку. Предупредил женщину, которой я ее дал, что она очень тяжела. Она ответила, что «Своя ноша не тяжела». Как это понимать? Она объяснила эту пословицу, но я её не понял.

Yesterday I gave my sewing machine away. I warned the lady I gave it to that it was heavy. She answered, "Своя ноша не тяжела". How to understand that phrase? She tried to explain it to me but I didn't understand.

Comment: By the way, in the sentence `Она ответила, что »Своя ноша не тяжела«` you did two mistakes.  First, quotes are used in Russian in the opposite way: `«Своя ноша не тяжела»` (you exchanged opening and closing quotes).  Second, `своя` should start with lowercase letter.  In Russian, capital letters are used more frugally.  "Я" should also be lowercase (unless it is the first word in a sentence). If a native Russian speaker writes "Я" in capital, he or she may be viewed as a pompous ass.

Comment: Do you think you don't *make* mistakes? Just edit the question.

Comment: Excellent. If that's the only problem you found with my Russian, then it is better than I thought!

Comment: Thanks to @DK for correcting grammatical mistakes; but why did you change машину to машинку?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Своя ноша не тяжела или Своя ноша не тянет.

This is a proverb that means "What is done for yourself is not hard".
Even if it is really a hard job.
Just to add the English equivalent

> "A burden of one's own choice is not felt".